# kubectl command line throws i/o timeout

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I deleted a cluster using the UI and since then any kubectl command throws this error

**kubectl get services**

`error: couldn't read version from server: Get https://107.178.212.121/api: dial tcp 107.178.212.121:443: i/o timeout`

**kubectl get nodes**

`error: couldn't read version from server: Get https://107.178.212.121/api: dial tcp 107.178.212.121:443: i/o timeout`

Not sure if its something wrong in my box.. everything was working fine just before deleting the cluster..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you delete the cluster, the master is deleted and you will no longer be able to connect. If you delete using the gcloud command line tool, it will clean up the kubeconfig entry for the cluster (and if you don't have any other entries kubectl will attempt to connect to localhost). If you delete the cluster through the UI, then the kubeconfig entry will remain unless you can clean it up yourself.